# Shortest path that going through top priority vertices in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given:

1.Directed graph $G=(V,E)$.

2.A set $U \subseteq V$ of top priority vertices such that $V\neq U\neq \emptyset $

3.Two vertices $s \neq t\in V$ such that $s,t\notin U$.

Find the shortest path from $s$ to $t$ that go through exactly 2 vertices $u_i , u_j \in U$. The path does not necessarily have to be simple

My thoughts:

I know that BFS can find the shortest path problem, but not with the current requirements and $G$.

I think I need  to make a reduction. Create a new graph $G^{'}=(V^{'},E{'})$ and run BFS.

I found a solution but I really want to solve it on my own before giving up.

How can I come to conclusions about what to change in the data input and reach the new graph. From where to start?

I want to design a new graph $G^{'}$ such that every path should have exactly two vertices from $U$, so What should I do if there's a path from $s$ to $t$ with more than two vertices from $U$ or maybe a path with less than two. It seems that I need to make duplicates but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: no they cannot be the same

Answer (score 1):

I can propose the following simple algorithm. For each vertex $u\in U$  find shortest paths avoiding $U$ (if they exist), $s-u$ from $s$ to $u$ and $u-t$ from $u$ to $t$. Also for each pair of (not necessarily) distinct vertices $u_i, u_j$ find a shortest path $u_i-u_j$ from $u_i$ to $u_j$ avoiding $U$ (if it exists). Now a required shortest path from $s$ to $t$ is a shortest among all concatenations of found $s-u_i$, $u_i-u_j$, and $u_j-t$.